# Display different image depending on xml output using xsl

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an xml (that i get from an external part) that outputs:

```
...<prop name="day">monday</prop>
<prop name="week">2</prop>...
```

I was wondering if it is at all possible to use xsl to display an image instead of the name of the day? The name of the day will change with 7 possible variables and I need to show a different image for each day of the week.

So the result I'm hoping for is something like this:

```
 <img src="mondayimage.jpg">
 <p>Week number 2</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In xslt 2.0 you van use the index-of xpath function to generate an efficient lookup:

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:param name="days" select="('monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday', 'saturday', 'sunday')"/>
    <xsl:param name="day-image" select="('image1.png','image2.png','image3.png','image4.png','image5.png','image6.png','image7.png')"/>

    <xsl:template match="/root">
        <root>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="prop[@name='day']">
        <img src="{$day-image[index-of($days, current())]}"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="prop[@name='week']">
        <p>Week number <xsl:value-of select="."/></p>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

[Working example](http://xsltransform.net/6qM2e25)

Answer (score 0):

you can make use of xsl:choose to handle your scenario.

Below I am including the code snippet that you can make use

```
<xsl:template match="prop">
    <xsl:variable name="day" select="."/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$day='monday'">
            <img src="mondayimage.jpg"/>
        </xsl:when>
       <!-- repeat condition for all the days -->
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <p><xsl:value-of select="@name"/> number <xsl:value-of select="."/> </p>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a different template for each type of prop, makes for easier changes later on. You can also use XSL code within a "{}" in strings to have a template that looks like the following:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:template match="root/prop[@name='day']">
        <img src="{.}image.jpg"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="root/prop[@name='week']">
        <p><xsl:value-of select="concat('Week number ',.)"/></p>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```